# How to make Socks request over http proxy?

Tags: ssl, proxy, socks

I have built an application called [Tun2Socks GUI](http://www.davicode.com/2014/02/new-release-2014-tun2socks-gui-v220-new.html). It's program to make Socks proxy o be transparent.

Usually it use SSH port forward or TOR as SOCKS service, but I want it can use HTTP proxy too. So I build SOCKS5 proxy my self that connect to that HTTP proxy. It's working good with capturing HTTP request from client to be sent to HTTP Proxy.

The problem when the client send SSL request, I cannot capture the request to be forwarded. How can I make SSL request from SOCKS proxy through HTTP Proxy?

Schema of request transportation like here :
*Client SSL request   >    SOCKS Proxy    >    HTTP Proxy   >    Internet*

Answer (score 4):

When a client intentionally wants to establish an SSL session with a target server through a proxy, it does not establish an SSL session with the proxy itself.  The client first tells the proxy to establish a connection to the target server, and THEN the client initiates an SSL session with the target server.  In that situation, it is not possible for the proxy to sniff the traffic as it is encrypted, nor should it be trying to.  A proxy is just a pass-through, it exchanges raw data back and forth between client and server as needed.  The proxy should not care what kind of requests the client is sending, since the client tells the proxy where to connect.

If you have injected your proxy in between the client and server in such a way that the client has no knowledge that your proxy exists, the client will not know that it needs to adjust its requests to make them proxy-friendly.  The client will be connected to your proxy but it will think it is connected to the target server, and thus will initiate an SSL handshake that your proxy will have to respond to.  Only then will your proxy have access to the client's request data (provided the handshake is successful, such as if the client does not verify peer certificates), and can then tunnel the unencrypted data to the next proxy as needed.

**Update**: I just thought of another scenario that should work for both cleartext and SSL connections.  Regardless of whether you are transparently redirecting the client's outbound connection to your SOCKS proxy without the client knowing about it, or the client intentionally connects to the SOCKS proxy and tells it where to go, the SOCKS proxy knows the client's target host/IP:port. The SOCKS proxy can either connect directly to the target, or it can connect to the HTTP proxy and ask it to create a tunnel to the target via the HTTP [`CONNECT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2817#section-5.2) method. If successful, the client has a viable connection to the target, and any data the client sends, SSL or otherwise, will flow as-is to the target, and vice versa.  Neither the SOCKS proxy nor the HTTP proxy needs to know anything about the client's request other than the target host/IP:port. That is in the initial SOCKS request, either captured from the intercepted TCP header, or explicit from the client.

Comment: If it just deliver traffic through SOCKS proxy as a gateway, I say YES. but the problem is I need deliver the traffic request over HTTP proxy too from the SOCKS proxy. the HTTP proxy Server sides cannot recognize the request, so then it cannot establish the connection to the right server target.

Comment: It sounds like you do not fully understand how an HTTP proxy works. Maybe you are unaware of the `CONNECT` method, or do not know how to use it correctly.

Comment: I do understand how to use CONNECT method. I just can't capture the SSL request packet from client in my SOCKS projects (only SSL packet).
For another request I do modifying header command because the genuine headers from client which produced SOCKS proxy, an HTTP proxy couldn't accept it.

here is my full source project code :
http://davidlorem.7uw.net/?258ceb85e3/davisocks.dpr

please check a procedure bellow which the problem was :

procedure SocksProc(sock : Cardinal); stdcall;

Comment: A proxy cannot intercept SSL encrypted content. The client creates the SSL session only after the tunnel to the target server has been created, so only the target can decrypt it. That ensures the integrity of the encryption between client and target and avoids man-in-the-middle attacks (you are a MITM). The only way to intercept SSL content is to act as the target server that the client talks to so you have your own SSL session with the client, and then act as your own client with a separate SSL session to forward data to another server. That is how Fiddler can intercept HTTPS, for example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So is acting like the target server something a TOR node could do? Or is this process on a "per server website" scheme? It seems impossible for this hijack to occur unless the target domain is hijacked and target server certs are copied.

Comment: @EDENDEKKER I don't know anything about how TOR works.